# Angular Js: Typeahead

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an input type which uses angularjs type-ahead.The problem I am facing is that it disappears when I move my mouse over it. I am able to use the arrow keys to select items from the list,but am unable to click and select from the list.

I am getting list from the database,and the typeahead list is populating fine. Other places I used almost the same code,it works fine. When using this particular typeahead, after a while,say 5-6 trials, it behaves normally.

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

My html:

```
<input
    id="{{roleAssignmentTableDTO.employeeNumberElementId}}" type="text"
    name="employeeNumber"
    ng-disabled="roleAssignmentTableDTO.disableEmployee"
    ng-model="roleAssignmentTableDTO.employeeNumber"
    typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue" />
```

My Controller:

```
$http
    .post('rest/employeeSearch', query)
    .success(
            function(dataList) {
                /*$scope.roleAssignmentDTO.roleAssignmentTableDTOList[elementId].searchLoader = false;
                roleAssignmentTableDTO.showSearchLink=true;*/

                if (dataList.length == 0) {
                    /*$scope.projectNotfoundError = true;
                    $scope.roleAssignmentDTO.roleAssignmentTableDTOList[elementId].showSearchLink = false;
                    $scope.projectNotfoundErrorMsg = 'You entered incorrect employee';*/
                }
                $.each(
                        dataList,
                        function(
                                i,
                                data) {
                            map[data.employeeNumber] = data;
                            List
                                    .push(data.employeeNumber);

                        });

                process(List);
            })
    .error(

            function() {
                $scope.roleAssignmentDTO.roleAssignmentTableDTOList[elementId].searchLoader = false;
                $scope.projectNotfoundError = true;
                $scope.projectNotfoundErrorMsg = 'Some Internal error occured';
                List
                        .push("no data found");
                process(List);
            });

    },
    updater : function(selectedData) {

    $scope.roleAssignmentDTO.roleAssignmentTableDTOList.employeeNumber = selectedData;

    return selectedData;
    }
    });
```

Comment: can you make a Plunkr to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Sorry, I have tried but there it works fine.no issue,whatsoever.

Comment: The thing is,when I try to move my mouse over the list of suggestions generated,the complete list disappears.

Comment: The javascript you posted is invalid and also formatted improperly.  Can you fix this?  I tried to format it for you, but I ran into issues because the JS is invalid.

Comment: yeah,this is not my complete js,only the code which is concerned with typeahead. Sorry for the inconvinience. Actual file is rather large.